# Regular Expression: 3 numbers over 4

Tags: regex

How do you write a regular expression that has at least 3 over 4?

Example:

28 -> false

5555 -> true

6498 -> true

332 -> false

234789 -> true

Thank you!

Comment: Don't you mean 3 digits greater than 4?

Comment: with *over* you mean *greater than*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?=(?:\d*[5-9]){3,})\d+$
```

You can use `lookahead` for this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/5